# php- inserting data into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner when we talk about PHP. SO I have no idea where I made a mistake using PHP.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$name = "yolo";
$surname = "yolo";
$nameOfFee= "asd";
$date = '2012-08-06';
$mysql_query = "(INSERT INTO Relation (Person_ID, Fee_ID, Date_of_fee)
SELECT Person.ID,Fee.ID,'$date'
FROM Person,Fee
WHERE Person.Name = '$name' AND Person.Surname = '$surname' AND Fee.Name_of_fee = '$nameOfFee');";

if($conn->query($mysql_query) === TRUE){
    echo "Insert completed";
}
else{
    echo "Insert not completed";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

It always puts that Insert is not complete...

Comment: could you add the error messages too?

Comment: Try checking your sql query in mysql, Is it even working ?

Comment: Yea I checked query in MySQL and it is working ...

Comment: @Swanson Please add the error message from the database to your question

Answer (score 1):

### The Problems

There are a few syntax errors in this piece of code you have provided:

```
// here it starts, what is this "(" for before insert?
// Take note that your query is vulnerable to SQL attacks
$mysql_query = "(INSERT INTO Relation (Person_ID, Fee_ID, Date_of_fee)
SELECT Person.ID,Fee.ID,'$date'
FROM Person,Fee
WHERE Person.Name = '$name' AND Person.Surname = '$surname' AND Fee.Name_of_fee = '$nameOfFee');";
```

### How to fix it

To fix these things I recommend you use the `MySQLi` OOP, like you are using now, but add prepared statements. I will walk through the new code with you so you can understand the process.

```
require "conn.php";
$name = "yolo";
$surname = "yolo";
$nameOfFee= "asd";
$date = '2012-08-06';

$sql = "INSERT INTO Relation (Person_ID, Fee_ID, Date_of_fee) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; // rewrite your query with a preset number of values to prevent SQL Attacks

if($stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql ))
{ // before we run check to make sure the query worked
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $nameOfFee, $date); // bind your variables so to know what goes where
    $stmt->execute(); // execute the query
    $stmt->close(); // close connection for safety
    // message as an array for the user as feedback.
    $message = array(
        'is_error' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Record was entered into database.'
    );
}
else
{
    $message = array(
        'is_error' => 'danger',
        'message' => 'Query Error, please revise the information.'
    );
}
```